# non-convex optimizatio

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, quadratic-programming

I have a question about non convex models. I deal with a Mixed Integer Quadratic problem (non convex quadratic objective function with linear constraints- product of two continuous variables in the objective function makes it non convex). I want to know about the exact methods for solving this type of problems to obtain the global optimum

Comment: This is perhaps too broad of a Question.  There may be no "optimum" without further assumptions.  If there are only two variables (your description is unclear), then the methods of calculus can most likely be applied to any specific problem.  Why not state a concrete example?